# Calculating the maximum histogram value

Tags: r, ggplot2

How can I calculate the maximum histogram value when making a plot?

I want to place a line on a plot with an annotation, and I want the text to be position proportional to the y-axis max value. For example:

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(x = runif(1000))


p <- ggplot(data=df, aes(x)) + geom_histogram()
p + geom_vline(aes(xintercept=0.5),color='red') + geom_text(aes(0.55, 10, label='line'), angle = 90, color='red')
```

produces the following:

[image]

I would like to pass an argument to `geom_text()` which is `1/3` of the max histogram value as I think this is the best way of positioning the text consistently, but I don't know how to calculate this `count` value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`stat_bin` uses binwidth=range/30 by default. I'm not sure exactly how it's calculated but this should be a fairly reasonable approximation:

```
max(table(cut(df$x,seq(min(df$x),max(df$x),dist(range(df$x))/30))))
```

Comment: Don't forget to multiply by 1/3 :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the hist function, which calculates the counts. Just make sure you pass it the same bin breaks as geom_histogram. In the case of not providing a binwidth to geom_histogram it defaults to range/30. From looking at how geom_histogram generates the bins I think this should work:

```
require(plyr)
min.brea <- round_any(min(df$x), diff(range(df$x))/30, floor)
max.brea <- round_any(max(df$x), diff(range(df$x))/30, ceiling)
breaks <- seq(min.brea, max.brea, diff(range(df$x/30)))
histdata <- hist(df$x, breaks=breaks, plot=FALSE, right=FALSE)
max.value <- max(histdata$counts)
```

the round_any function is from plyr.